# How do i post to external API from within current API - with POST JSON body?

Tags: express

**Background:**

I've got a current Express.js API that accepts a GET request.

The controller method then must take that request and construct a JSON object then post it to another - completely external - API.  Then it must take the response from *that* external API and then communicate back in its *own* response.

**Current Code:**

```
const request = require("request");

exports.requestForExternalInfo = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

// this is the JSON I want to include in the call to an external API:
  let externalPostType = {
    "carInfo": {
      "InfoType": "VIN"
    }
  };

request.post("https://externaldomain.com/api/v1/carinforequest", externalPostType, (error, response, body) => {
   const res = JSON.parse(body)
});

  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    data: res,
  });
});
```

**Question:**

Does Express.js have something that can handle this?  I don't know if my current usage of the "request" package is the correct solution or not.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to solve this problem by using the Post-man-generated call.  Turns out Postman will provide you with the exact syntax needed to make an independent call out to another API.  (As long as you've constructed that independent API call in Postman and have it working with all necessary headers and body).

It's a simple solution to the problem; otherwise if you want to explore another possible answer, you can try Rahul Pal's answer below.  I would have marked his as the preferred solution, but I honestly feel the more straight-forward approach is to try using the syntax provided by Postman.

**Postman Solution:**

In the Postman tool (which you'd have to independently install and use if you haven't already - it's a very common API testing tool):

1. Go to 'Code' (directly under the 'save' button in latest version as of 2020)  [image]
2. choose 'Nodejs-Axios'
3. Copy code and paste it where appropriate
4. Make sure to import Axios as well

   const axios = require("axios");

Hopefully this short-cut approach - thanks to the devs at Postman - helps others as it certainly provided a fast solution for what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can send the response back to your own server once the external API request has completed
You can call res.send in the callback handler of the request package.

```
exports.requestForExternalInfo = asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {

    let externalPostType = {
        "carInfo": {
            "InfoType": "VIN"
        }
    };

    request.post("https://externaldomain.com/api/v1/carinforequest", externalPostType, (error, response, body) => {
        let res = JSON.parse(body)

        /* send the response to you server from inside this request callback handler */
        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            data: res,
        });

    });

});
```